# Dynamically configure connection manager for multiple source types

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a table, similar to the one below, on my DB that stores a list of data sources that I would like to import into my DB using SSIS.

[image: Source Tables]

I have done this by having a six data flow tasks, one for every file type and and a corresponding connection manager for that file type in each DFT.

Other than the different connection managers, the logic is the same for each DFT and I was wondering if there is a way I can combine all of these into one DFT and configure the connection manager on the fly based on the SourceTypeID.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Utilize an OLE or ODBC connection manager and dynamically build connection string in a variable as applicable to your source.  You are very likely going to hit other problems with source types (eg numeric in Oracle vs MySQL vs ...) - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cfe67e7-ff6e-43df-b986-605dbf278f18/change-dynamically-connections-during-runtime-using-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for BiML, which lets you dynamically build packages based on meta-data.